# How to mark large blocks of code

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Sometimes I need to quote some larger blocks of code. Pasting that from an IDE, I have to add four spaces at the beginning of every line to get the text formatted as code.

That is a little bit annoying, if I have to add those foure spaces for a larger amount of lines of code.

Is there an easyier way to format blocks of text as code. (Except for using pastebin and linking it ;))

Thanks in advance

Comment: @JoshCaswell You are right. Sorry!

Comment: you do know about the {} button yes?

Comment: @ledino Now, I do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a `{}` button that will automatically indent all highlighted text:

[image]

This button has the same effect as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. I tend to use the button, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: Thanks. That works too.

Comment: @t777 Glad I could help.

Comment: +1 for freehand circle

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the code segment and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

All code that is indented four spaces is considered a code block.

```
Something like this.
```

Knowing this, I ensure that, before I paste the code, all of the code is indented four spaces in beforehand (and all tabs are converted to appropriately distanced spaces).

Failing this, highlighting all of the code I want to format and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is an approach.  Be careful of mixing and matching tabs and spaces though - that can wreck formats.